# Laravel does not return query results

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i am trying to query a database table in laravel 8

```
$password_resets = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $value)->first();
```

the table name is correct, the record with the concerned value does exist but the query is returning null results.

```
DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $value)->toSql();
```

returns

```
select * from `password_resets` where `email` = ?
```

Comment: What is in your `return` statement?

Comment: DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $value)->dd(); run it to see the raw query tha t is executing.

Comment: the return is null

Comment: Try this: dd (DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $value)->toSql());
and chekc waht you get.

Comment: it shows : select * from `password_resets` where `email` = ?

Comment: are you sure about the value of $value? dd($value) would tell you whats inside it. check if its exactly what you want

Comment: Check what `$value` contains. Make sure there aren't any wayward spaces, or capitalization differences.

Comment: Can you post your full controller logic?

Comment: dd($value) returns what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to insert a static valid email that exists and then see the result, if it does then there will have a problem in $value

```
$password_resets = DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', 'abc@gmail.com')->first();
dd($password_resets);
```

don't forget to write

```
use DB;
```